# Android ActionBar has unwanted black triangle

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

[image]This one has me stumped.  I'm using the v7 ToolBar and v4 DrawerLayout.  I've got it where the main Fragments use the drawer and users can drill down into other Fragments, which changes the drawer toggle to a back arrow or other custom home up indicator.  But, for some reason, there's this little black down arrow (almost like a dropdown's there) just to the right of the ActionBar logo / title.  The title and subtitle are null.  The logo and custom home up indicators definitely don't have an arrow on the drawables.  There's also no buttons on the ActionBar.

What's even more weird is when I use the home up indicator to go back to a previous Fragment, another arrow appears.  So, I start getting multiple arrows.

So any ideas what this arrow is and how to turn it off?

Environment:
ADT 1.1.0
Targeting API 14 to 21
Android 5.0.1 (Nexus 4) and 5.0.2 (Nexus 7 2013)
Using ActionBarActivity with support Fragments

Edit: added sample screenshot of what I'm seeing.

Comment: sounds like you have a spinner with no data in your Toolbar, can you share the layout.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the action bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did finally find the solution.  In your app theme, add this line:

```
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@null</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the compat toolbar, I explicitly set these resources:

```
mToolbar.getMenu().clear(); // to to prevent stacking
mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_arrow_back);
mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        finish();
    }
});
```

You can get the full set of material icons via the Intellij plugin: Android Drawable Importer.

You can see a more complete tutorial here: 
http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-toolbars-in-your-apps.html

The black arrow my guess is is the deprecated navigation icon: http://cdn2.androidhive.info/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/android-action-bar-overview1.png?805852

Comment: I did not have any luck with the above code you gave. :-(  Can you look at my screenshot and see if the small arrow makes sense to you?

Comment: That looks like a unicode character where your toolbar title should be. Try explicitly setting your toolbar title to "".

Comment: Sadly, that didn't work.  I also had tried setTitle(null) and setSubtitle(null) previously.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Fire up hierarchyviewer, start your activity in an emulator: use the viewer to inspect what that is / what it belongs to.

Comment: Ashton - I tried that.  I saw SpinnerCompat @213e7847.  Any ideas on that?  I've tried grepping for that ID and just don't see it.

Comment: It looks like for some reason you have a spinner action bar style: since you have not set adapter all you see is the black triangle (indicating the spinner drop down). You'll have to add either your xml and code (layout and/or theme) relating to this actionbar to diagnos what's wrong: but it looks like you are inadvertently using a style that sets a spinner in your actionbar.

Comment: Ashton - I'm using Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar as the parent.  I tried looking through the source and didn't see anything that seemed to help.  I did try modifying the androidDropDownStyle, but to no avail.  Any ideas?

Comment: Post your xml / code related to this. Use hierarchyviewer to see what is going on there: as I said it looks like you've inadvertantly set up a spinner in your actionbar.

Answer (score -1):

if your `base activity` has following code:

```
mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
```

comment out this line .